# Is there any way to disable/prevent options to "Open in a new tab/window" when using RouterLink in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, router, routerlink

I have a single page application and using RouterLink in anchor tag() to navigate to other pages without refresh.

```
<ul class="menu">
          <li *ngIf="isContain(adminFilterMenuItems, 'Setup')">
            <a id="NavSetupButton" routerLink="/setup">
              <img alt="Setup" src="./assets/images/Setup.png" />
            </a>
          </li>
</ul>
```

I have the requirement to disable a few options on right click such as "Open in a new tab", "Open in a new window" etc, not disable entire context menu, I need the context menu.

I have observed that when I do not use RouterLink and implement other logic to navigate, I do not see those options on right click, which I want. But I am using RouterLink and don't want to mess with entire application for such a requirement.

Is there any way to disable a few options of context menu on right click while using RouterLink for navigation?

Comment: This is down to the html that is being generated. Using `[routerLink]` will generate an anchor element with an href attribute. The browser will treat this as a regular link and offer whatever options it would normally ask on a link. It sounds like you've already experimented with other methods that work for you - why not use them?

Comment: Added an answer which worked for me

Comment: @KurtHamilton Yes I experimented and found a solution which works, but it feels like patch work to me, I was looking for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround which works for me.
Instead of using RouterLink, I called the click event and wrote a method "navigateTo",
so this click event will call my "navigateTo" method which will do the job of page navigation.

**HTML File**

```
<ul class="menu">
      <li *ngIf="isContain(adminFilterMenuItems, 'Setup')">
        <a id="NavSetupButton" (click)="navigateTo('/setup')">
          <img alt="Setup" src="./assets/images/Setup.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

**component.ts**

```
  navigateTo(component) {
    this.router.navigate([component]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The list of options on a right click is called context menu. There are multiple ways to disable it. The answer mentioned before (`oncontextmenu="return false;"`) is an elegant solution.

However since this is an Angular related question, let us write an Attribute Directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDisableRightClick]'
})
export class DisableRightClickDirective {
  @HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event']) onContextMenu($event: any) {
    $event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Now it can be passed to the anchor tag with the `[routerLink]` directive. For eg.

```
<a routerLink="sample" appDisableRightClick>About</a>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlink-ssf-kicdyd)

In the StackBlitz application, context menu is disabled for links 'About' and 'Services' while link 'Testing' is unmodified.

---

**Explanation**:
[`HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) decorator declares a DOM event to listen to and provides a method for event handling. We listen to the [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) event which is usually triggered when the right mouse button or context menu key is clicked. In the implementation, the event's [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method is called which tells the browser its default action should not be taken as it normally would be. Which in our case disables the context menu from opening.

---

Application forked from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlink-ssf).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I do not want to entirely disable the context menu, but just a few options. I found a workaround, added an answer myself

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try oncontextmenu event on anchor tah like in below example.

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" oncontextmenu="return false;"> Link </a>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I do not want to entirely disable the context menu, but just a few options. I found a workaround, answering the question myself now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to incorporate this in your code

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" oncontextmenu="return false;">W3schools</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I do not want to entirely disable the context menu, but just a few options. I found a workaround, added an answer myself